# Illegalargumentexception : java.net.URISyntaxException : Relative path in absolute path URI getting while reading json files recursively from ADLSS

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

Folder structure:

```
A -> B1->C1->.json
  -> B2->C2->.json
```

There can be many folders under A and B which doesn't follow any pattern.

The above is the folder structure in ADLS while reading Json files recursively using spark we are getting below error.

> java.net.URISyntaxException : Relative path in absolute path URI

```py
def json_parquet(sourceFilePath):
  df=(spark.read.format("json")
      .option("multiline",True)
      .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
      .option("pathGlobFilter","*.json")
      .load(sourceFilePath))

sourceFilepath='dbfs:/mnt/pp-working-1/A'

json_parquet(sourceFilepath)
```

It is working fine with S3 mnt but failing with ADLS mnt.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above and able to get all the JSON files stored in multiple subfolders successfully using your code.

This my folder structure in ADLS and I have mounted till `databricksfolder`.

```
databricksfolder
    folder1
        folder3
            folder5
                Sample2.json
            Sample2.json
        folder4
            sub1
                Sample2.json
            Sample2.json
        Sample2.json
    folder2
        sub2
            Sample2.json
        Sample2.json
    Sample2.json
```

I have 5 rows each in the above 8 files and able to get the 40 rows dataframe using your code.

```
df=spark.read.format("json").option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").option("pathGlobFilter","*.json").load("dbfs:/mnt/mount1/")
display(df)
```

[image]

Recheck again from your end and if the error still persists you can try this alternative.

Get the all the file paths list recursively using the `glob`

```
import glob
l=[]
for file in glob.iglob('/dbfs/mnt/mount1/**/*.json',recursive=True):
    l.append(file[6:])
print(l)
```

This gives all the file paths list recursively like this.

[image]

Use this list to read the JSONs into a dataframe.

```
df2=spark.read.format("json").load(l)
display(df)
```

[image]